# How to receive user input in oracle form at run-time?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger that processes a sale transaction, inside the trigger there is a check of the sale transaction amount.

If the amount is greater than 1000 the authorization code from the senior is needed.

How will I receive that authorization code while still inside the trigger?

I tried to call a new canvas to receive the authorization code, but the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger continues to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Raise `form_trigger_failure` exception to cancel trigger processing. User then enters authorization code and cliks button again.

```
...
if :your_block.amount > 1000 then
    message('Enter authorization code');
    raise form_trigger_failure;
end if;

-- here continue your transaction
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I want to prompt the user to enter the authorization code without raising an exception. In Java you can use a Scanner class to receive an input from the user. e.g. 
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int n = reader.nextInt();

Comment: Please see the workaround without using a canvas : "A new canvas won't do it; however, if you call another form (which accepts the authorization code), WBP trigger will wait until you return back from the called form and then continue its execution. " http://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/657510/#msg_657510

Comment: yes, this will work. You can develop typical "dialogs" and use them from other forms. Be aware of transaction, called form can have its own, but I think its not problem in your case.